# What does it mean to compute a normal to a triangle in a "clockwise direction"

Tags: matrices, geometry

I am trying to understand how this works.

I am given 3 points, each representing a vertex of a triangle. I must then "organise" the points and calculate the normal of the resulting triangle in a "clockwise direction"

I have no idea what this means can some one please enlighten me.

EDIT: Here is a picture of what I am failing to understand.

[image]

I don't understand what they mean by the **NOTE:** part. If 5 random points are given to me, how am I supposed to organise them like that. (By the way I know this is a polygon but it will apply for a triangle too I think)

Comment: If you traverse the points in the clockwise direction, the normal will point down instead of up in your figure.  Also, there is no unique way of finding the connectivity of 5 randomly placed points unless additional assumptions are made, e.g., the domain that they enclose is convex.

Comment: Well if the domain they enclose is convex, and the vertices are roughly co-planar, how could I organise them then?

Comment: The typical approach is to compute the [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of the set of points.  You can see a number of algorithms [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms).  Keep in mind that the orientation of the points depends on which side of the plane you are looking at it from.  So the direction of the normal and the clockwise/counter-clockwise orientation of the points are two ways of saying the same thing.